# Adding extra column to existing Table in SQL with more than 6 million records

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

[image]

Using SQL

I want to insert a new column in the existing table which will derive its value from other two columns in particular where value ( Desk+Field ) . The table already contains 6 million records .

Can someone explain me how this can be done?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*two columns in particular where value*"? What kind of `where` condition are you talking about?

Comment: Desk column and Field column . New column should have values in format of AGY.LT_Strat#Submit_BmkPricingInput

Comment: What's a "Desk Column"? And even more confusing a "*Field* column"?

Comment: Image clearly states Desk is a column name and so is the field. I will be more than happy to be more clear on the question if you want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By doing this you will be introducing redundancy since the same data is already stored.  Should the joining of these two fields not occur in your business logic as opposed to the database?

Comment: Correct but i require it so that i don't do a join on 5 fields. (desk+Field) is just an example. Using TVP i will be doing join  against single field

Comment: Would you not be better doing the join on the 5 columns and adding an index then?  By adding fields in this manner you would be de-normalizing the state of your DB.  I appreciate adding an index would increase the burden of adding new records etc. but that would just be a trade-off that you would have to weigh up.  Otherwise, what happens if some time down the line you have a requirement where you decide that you need to join the values of three fields in a new column...you're data becomes more unmanageable as you have to maintain it in multiple places

Comment: I am looking for the design i mentioned above. I appreciate your advice. But it would be good to know if the question i asked is possible or not.

Comment: If your convinced tyou need to go this route then - Based on the MySQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html  you cannot have a computed default value, therefore the solution would probably have to be along the lines of: 1. add the column (making it nullable), 2. create a trigger to set the value of the column on insert (and update if neccessary), 3. write a query to do an insert to populate the new column for all current records.  This should leave you in a position where all current and subsequent records will have the value set.